# Passing parameters to a shell script running as a cronjob

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I am new to bash scripting (not programming in general).

I am writing a bash script that will run a Python script I have written.

I want to be able to do the following:

- Pass parameters to the bash script via the cronjob (so I can have two cron jobs) one to be run with parameter 'foobar', and the other 'foo'
- switch based on the parameter passed to the bash script (by switching, I mean an if/else based on the paramter passed to the bash script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was thinking of referring you to stackoverflow, but this is such low level 'programming' it may be best to just do it here.

The first parameter to a shell script is referenced by `$1`, the second `$2`, etc...  The tenth can't be called `$10` because that's `$1` followed by a `0`, so you refer to it as `${10}`, though if you need to refer to the tenth parameter explicitly (and not handling it in a loop) you're probably doing something wrong.

The count of parameters is in the variable `$#`

I'd suggest:

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "No parameter given" >&2
    exit 1
elif [ "$1" == 'foo' ]
then
    ./script someparams ....
elif [ "$1" == 'foobar' ]
then
    ./script otherparams ....
else
    echo "Bad parameter given" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Always put double quotes around parameter substitutions, otherwise the shell will split them into words. (Yeah, I know, now you don't even imagine putting special characters there, but tomorrow you'll put a space in a file name and wonder why your scripts break, or you'll do this in a CGI script and wonder why your website was cracked.)

Comment: You can use a `case` statement to avoid a long sequence of `if` and `elif` if you're going to have more than just a few options.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `getopts` for a more flexible way of passing arguments to bash script. By using `getopts` you can remove the fixed ordering associated with the arguments you are passing, which has the risk of passing wrong data if you forget the order of argument.

Comment: *Passing* arguments works jus the same, you simply change how you *receive/process* them.

Answer (score 1):

Another form for `if..elif..elif..else..fi` is the `case` statement

```
case "$1" in
  foobar) 
    ./script.py arg1 arg2
    ;;
  foo)
    ./script.py arg3 arg4
    ;;
  *)
    echo "unknown argument: $1"
    ;;
esac
```

`case` uses glob-style matching, so the `*` means "everything else"

You'll find that bash is a pretty finicky language, where quoting or not quoting a variable can cause big differences in how your script runs. Get into the habit of quoting all your variables.